# Google Docs: trying to get a heading section to stay on the same page as the previous text

Tags: google-docs

I'm working on a google docs project and which has a lot of headings followed by lists. For instance, a heading with ten references and then another section of normal text.

What I would LIKE to happen is when I reach this heading section is to have a couple of blank lines followed by the heading and next section beginning on the same page.
Ex.

```
Page1__
--text----
----------

Heading
--text---
---text--

Different Heading
________________
```

What happens is whenever I add section of text prefaced by a heading Google Docs throws it in its own page no matter how much space is left on the previous page. This looks ugly and I'm trying to find a way to circumvent it.

What happens:

```
Page1__
--text----
----------
[blank space is here]

Page2___
Heading
--text---
---text--
[blank space is here]

Page3__
Different Heading
________________
```

*All of the text would neatly fit on one page if I could figure out how to get google docs to **let** me just use that one page.* Is there a way to force docs to use all the space on a page before going to the next one?